# How to reduce Apps memory After Updating

Tags: applications, internal-storage, facebook

Whenever I update my apps it gets double the size. For example, the Facebook app has around 27-31 Mb of space on Android. But once I update this app it's showing 50Mb and above.

Currently my phone's Facebook app showing 115MB size. I updated this app for six times. So I want to reduce that size as app's original size. And if I uninstall the app and reinstalling it still shows 115MB Size.

Please advise me on how to reduce the app size after updating it?

Answer (score 0):

I would click "clear data" under the app manager settings for this app, but kepp in mind it will rest your app back to when you very first installed it E.g Your not logged in,changed back to default settings etc.

I know this cant be your only solution, as I would hate to put everything back the way I like it but this can help reduce sizes.

Alternative: Use Links2Sd to move apps to a second partition on your SD card (Give this partition a decent size) and you wont have to worry about your phones internal memory filling up.